# How do you show a loading indicator and then swap it out with content in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, activity-indicator

I noticed that a lot of the popular apps have a loading indicator that then gets replaced with content.  Most of the views are UITableViews.  I'm enclosing a screenshot below with the Medium app which shows the indicator.  When the asynchronous content for the Home feed is fetched, then the loading spinner gets replaced with the content.

I saw a lot of examples online of how to do loading indicators mention the following CocoaPod: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD.  However, this is different, it actually has a black/gray container label with the spinner appear on top of the entire view.  Most popular apps don't do this (Facebook, Twitter, Medium), I much prefer to have a nice loading spinner that's on the content area which then gets swapped out.

I guess I'm confused the approach they use. Is it a separate UIView with a white background and a spinner that they show and hide on top of the table? Is it part of the table view? I'm guessing it's a UIActivityIndicator for the spinner itself.

How would one go about doing this in iOS (via Swift)?

[Medium iOS app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR0id.png)

Comment: Are you asking how to create a spinner view, or how to use one, or both?

Comment: I guess I'm confused the approach they use.  Is it a separate UIView with a white background and a spinner that they show and hide?  Is it part of the table view?  I'm guessing it's a UIActivityIndicator for the spinner itself.

Comment: The built in `UIActivityIndicatorView` is indeed a separate view.  It is hidden until you call `startAnimating` and hides again when you call `stopAnimating`.  It has a transparent background so all you see is the spinner.  You'd add it as a subview of some view that is on screen, call `startAnimating`, start up some background task, and when the background task is done, you'd call `stopAnimating` on the spinner from the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You just set the background view of your table to a spinner.

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
```

Then set it to nil when your content loads (when you call `reloadData`)